# How to get particular value from Dropdown list in Flutter | Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have a list of items that were received from API. I want to print a particular value of that selected item from the list. The list is,

```
[
    {
      'id': '1',
      'name': 'roy',
      'designation': 'engineer',
    },
    {
      'id': '2',
      'name': 'john',
      'designation': 'doctor',
    },
    {
      'id': '3',
      'name': 'rose',
      'designation': 'clerk',
    }
  ];
```

From this list, if I select john from the dropdown menu then it should print the designation in the console. If I select `rose` then it prints `clerk` in the console. How to achieve this. Below is my code,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
List users = [
    {
      'id': '1',
      'name': 'roy',
      'designation': 'engineer',
    },
    {
      'id': '2',
      'name': 'john',
      'designation': 'doctor',
    },
    {
      'id': '3',
      'name': 'rose',
      'designation': 'clerk',
    }
  ];
  String? userId;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton(
            isExpanded: true,
            hint: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text('Select Item'),
            ),
            value: userId,
            items: users.map((item) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(item['name']),
                value: item['id'].toString(),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (String? newValue) {
              setState(() {
                userId = newValue;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What code I need to add inside onChanged function to get designation of that selected user.

Answer (score 0):

```
items: users.map((item) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(item['name']),
                value: item['designation'].toString(),
              );
            }).toList(),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?